# Python - TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples, runtime-error

When trying to buy things in my 'shop', the shell crashes with a "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" message. Also, the code runs fine up until I try to buy something.

```
def store():
    os.system('cls')
    print("Welcome to the shop!")
    print("What would you like to buy?")
    print("1.) Greatsword - 40 gold")
    print("0.) Back")
    print(' ')
    option = input(' ')

    if option in weapons:
        if PlayerIG.gold >= weapons[option]:
            os.system("cls")
            PlayerIG.gold -= weapons[option]
            PlayerIG.weap.append(option)
            print("You have bought %s!" % option)
            option = input(' ')
            store()
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            print("You cannot afford this.")
            option = input(' ')
            store()

    elif option == "Back":
        start1()
    else:
      os.system("cls")
      print("That item does not exist.")
      option = input(' ')
      store()
```

Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Amalgia Arena\AmalgiaArena.py", line 284, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Amalgia Arena\AmalgiaArena.py", line 60, in main
    start()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Amalgia Arena\AmalgiaArena.py", line 90, in start
    start1()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Amalgia Arena\AmalgiaArena.py", line 109, in start1
    store()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Amalgia Arena\AmalgiaArena.py", line 262, in store
    if PlayerIG.gold >= weapons[option]:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've looked at other code with the same errors and their solutions, but I'm extremely new to Python, and as such I couldn't figure out what I needed to fix. If there's any more code I need to post, then I will. Also, I'm new to this site, so if you want to bash me for whatever reason (bad question, bad code, etc.), then please do so. I'm willing to learn :D

Comment: `option` is of type `str`

Answer (score 1):

The return value of an `input` is a string, just add `weapons[int(option)]` to change to a integer.

EDIT: undo the above. All you did was define `weapons` as a tuple instead of a dictionary. Just change the definition to `weapons = {'Greatsword', 40}`

Comment: I did that and got a new error. Traceback: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Greatsword'

Comment: @C.Riggs what is `weapons`

Comment: Toward the beginning of the code (right after I imported all the things) I have "weapons = ("Greatsword", 40)". 'weapons' is where I plan on storing all the weapons, "Greatsword" is the name of the weapon, and "40" is how much it costs. Did I format this wrong?

Comment: Okay, I've made it a dictionary and got a new error. I think I'm just going to create a class for weapons and see if that will work. Thanks for your help and patience, I appreciate it.